# Using Shims to test private method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mstest, shim

I am trying to use Shim to test one of my private method in this class called DataSyncCore.
Apologies if this is too trivial as i am new to shims and can't figure out why this is giving me an error saying "The property or indexer GetEnvironmentString cannot be used in this context as it is lacking an accessor.  How can this be fixed?

```
//Method to be tested inside DataSyncCore Class 
private Environments GetEnvironment(string env)
{
   string environment = env.ToLower();

   switch (environment)
   {
      case "dev":
         return Environments.Dev;
      case "qc":
         return Environments.QC;
      case "uat":
         return Environments.UAT;
      case "prod":
         return Environments.PROD;
      default:
         return Environments.Dev;
   }
}
```

This is my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DataSyncCore_GetsEnvironment_Succeeded()
{
   using (ShimsContext.Create())
   {
      var core = new ShimDataSyncCore()
      {
         GetEnvironmentString = (dev) =>
         {
            return Environments.Dev;
         }
      };
      Assert.AreEqual(Environments.Dev, core.GetEnvironmentString("dev"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, the term `Accessor` (get keyword) and its complimentary `Mutator` (set keyword) tells me that you are missing a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: From the examples i have seen i don't have a clue how to do that. Thank you Brain for your comment

Comment: This is a compiler error, which is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8cktb3y(v=vs.80).aspx).  It would be helpful if you could post more of your code.

Comment: Hi Brian! thank you for looking into it. I think microsoft error message is misleading us here. i strongly believe after carrying out a simple test it should be core.instance.GetEnvironmentString("dev") for it to work. i'll test and report accordingly when i am back to office on Monday

Comment: Hi Sike...  Just curious if you the test you mentioned above worked?

Comment: Hi Brian! Sorry i couldn't test it today. I Will definately do it tomorrow and write the conclusion :)

Comment: Sounds great, will talk to you then.

Comment: That didn't work for some strange reason. so i think the conclusion would be not to use Shims at all in testing private methods. It seems like we can mock the private methods but we cannot execute asserts with them. So i think the best way to test these methods is to call them from public methods and test public methods instead to ensure their accuracy. Thank you for your contribution Brian

Comment: I think that solution sounds much better, and you are most welcome for the help (although I don't think I helped much :P).

Comment: Every Little Helps Brian :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot make the class public, you can still use Activator.CreateInstance:

var anInstance = (YourPrivateClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourPrivateClass), true);

Or, you could mark the method as internal and set InternalsVisibleTo attribute in your assemblyinfo if you want/need to test that method directly.